# Bash: Why does variable containing string a equate to string b in an if statement?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, sh

I set a prompt to get user input Yy/Nn. Then I check if the response matches Y/y or N/n. However everytime it evaluates to true on "$prompt_1"="Y"/"y" even when you answer N/n. Now I am sure there is a reason why, however searching around brought me to a few solutions IG: Qoutes around the variables. But nothing has helped to resolve this.

```
#!/bin/bash



clear;
echo "Would you like to proceed with installation?"
read prompt_1;

echo $prompt_1;

if [ "$prompt_1"="Y" ] || [ "$prompt_1"="y" ]; then
  echo "You've accepted installation";


elif [ "$prompt_1”="N"] || [ “$prompt_1"="n" ]; then
  exit;
fi
```

Comment: Could be shorter: `if [ ${prompt_1,,} = y ]; then ...`

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) autodetects many common issues including these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add spaces around the `=` operator:

```sh
if [ "$prompt_1" = "Y" ] || [ "$prompt_1" = "y" ]; then
  echo "You've accepted installation";
elif [ "$prompt_1" = "N" ] || [ "$prompt_1" = "n" ]; then
  exit;
fi
```

Or using the pattern-matching operator `=~`  in a `[[...]]` expression:

```sh
if [[ "$prompt_1" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    echo "You've accepted installation";
elif [[ "$prompt_1" =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]; then
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The case statement solution.

```
case $prompt_1 in
  [Yy]) echo "You've entered $prompt_1 and accepted installation."
  ##: do something here 
  ;;
  [Nn]) echo "You entered $prompt_1 and did not accepted the installation."
   exit
   ;;
  *|'') echo "Unknown option ${prompt_1:-empty}."  ##: not [Nn] or [Yy] or empty.
   exit
  ;;
esac
```

- That is not restricted to bash anymore, it should work on other POSIX sh shells too.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, using `case` and lower case substitution:

```
case ${prompt_1,,} in
    y|yes|"just do it")
        echo "You've accepted installation"
        # perform installation
        ;;
    n|no|forget) exit;;
    *) echo "Wrong answer, try again";;
esac
```

PS: Works in bash4 or later.

Comment: @Jetchisel There is shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the question and bash4 was released more then 10 years ago.